# VS Code and SFDX (salesforce) error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: salesforcedx, visualstudiocode

I'm using Windows 10 + VS Code + Salesforce. From some point when I need to connect to Salesforce org. (make a push or just open it) I get the error "Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain", and "code: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN". As far as I understand, there are several ways to solve this problem: set strict-ssl=false, or set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 (this options is not recommended from the point of view of security), or set the path to the certificate to the NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS environment variable. This last way I would like to use.

The problem is that there are no NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS environment variables at all on my computer. I created them myself (2 identical variables: system and for this user) and specified the path to the .cer file that I created using the Certificate Export Wizard on my Salesforce org page. I partially used this article (partially. because there is a solution for git and I do not know how to use it completely for salesforce) : https://mattferderer.com/fix-git-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain-on-windows. But it didn't change anything, I still get the same error, for example, when I use the in VS Code " sfdx force:org:open " command. Maybe I was doing something wrong.
I need detailed instructions: where and how to get the certificate, how to add it to the variable value and what to do after. I will also be happy with other solutions to the problem (without NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS), if it is a permanent solution.

Screen with error from VS Code terminal:
[image]

Comment: If you do `echo $NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` in your terminal, is the result empty? I suspect you'll find that it is. If you do `export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=<path to file>` and then run your build again, does it work?

Comment: I don't understand you. I checked the fact of the presence of environment variables through the "System Properties". Where exactly should I write the "echo" and "export" commands? What exactly does "run your build again" mean?

Comment: You should run those commands in your terminal in Visual Studio Code. Then, try again to open your org.